How can i dynamically inject values in @Values annotations? (Spring Java)
application.properties contain the given information:
book.name1 = War and Piece
book.author1 = Leo Tolstoy
book.name2 = Crime and Punishment
book.author2 = Dostoevsky 
book.name3 = To Kill a Mockingbird
book.author3 = Harper Lee

And a Book.java, which takes values from the file
public class Book {
    String name;
    String author;
    static int bookid = 0;
    
    public Book(){bookid++;}
    
    @Value ("${book.name.concat(bookid)}")
    public void setName(String name)
    {this.name = name;}
    
    @Value ("${book.author.concat(bookid)}")
    public void setAuthor(String name)
    {this.author = author;}
    
    public String getBook()
    {return name + " by " + author;}
}

And at last class that contains an Arraylist of books
public class UniversityLibrary implements Library{
    List<Book> books;
    public UniversityLibrary(ArrayList<Book> books) //books are injected by ConfigClass
    {
        this.books = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Book bok: books)
        {this.books.add(bok);}
    }
}

The result of System.out.println(ubilibrary.getBook(1)) is ${book.name.concat(bookid)} by ${book.author.concat(bookid)} - as expected, but does not satisfies the task. Creating a single Book wouldn't really help the situation either.
Nowhere found the right syntaxis to make this work. I expect the expression in Value to take value from bookid and concat it with ${book.name..} to get in result @Value("${book.name1}") and etc...

That is not what application.properties is for. A first step might be to have a csv file with your dynamically changing values or better yet, connect your application to a database.

Your book looks like a classic Entity.

you understand that have an id as static will result it having the same value across ALL books

it is possible with @ConfigurationProperties
Provided you have the following properties:
books[0].name = War and Piece
books[0].author = Leo Tolstoy
books[1].name = Crime and Punishment
books[1].author = Dostoevsky 
books[2].name = To Kill a Mockingbird
books[2].author = Harper Lee

you can autowire these properties to a List<Book>:
@ConfigurationProperties
@Component // we either have to define it as component or specifically instruct Spring to scan for this with `@ConfigurationPropertiesScan`
public class BookProperties {

    private List<Book> books;

    // IMPORTANT! without a setter, spring won't bind the values
    public void setBooks(List<Book> books) {
        this.books = books;
    }

    // getter
}

Afterwards you can autowire BookProperties whereever you need and access the booksList (books)
For more info see relevant documentation

Regarding bookid you should also define it in properties or add logic into a setter BUT it can't be static otherwise it will have the same value across ALL book objects (because that is how static works, it is a class level property, NOT instance level)

bookid wasn't really a good name for this static field. It should've incremented every time new book is added (total_books). Thanks for your contribution! I'll try to work with this one

So, following J Asgarov advice, i ended up with this properties:
list.books[0].name = War and Piece
list.books[0].author = Leo Tolstoy ...

turns out, this synaxis is crucial for @ConfigurationProperties. Next goes Book class, no @Value's are used!(Which was new for me)
public class Book {
    String name;
    String author;
    public void setName(String name)
    {this.name = name;}

    public void setAuthor(String author)
    {this.author = author;}

    public String getBook()
    {return name + " by " + author;}
}

BookProperties or UniLibrary in my case follows this pattern:
@ConfigurationProperties("list") // and this is why list.* in properties is important!!
public class UniversityLibrary implements Library{
    List<Book> books;
    //setter goes here
    //...
}

And last but not least: ConfigClass. Except @EnableAspectJAutoProxy (proxyTargetClass=true), make sure you have them all
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("koroler.spring.AOP")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan 
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy (proxyTargetClass=true)
public class ConfigClass {
    @Bean
    @Scope ("prototype")
    public Book books()
    {
        return new Book();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public UniversityLibrary uniLibrary()
    {
        return new UniversityLibrary();
    } 
}

As a result, ulibrary.getBook(1) returns Crime and Punishment by Dostoevsky as expected. Thanks alot! I also hope, that this answer would help someone if you're stuck a bit with another solutions c:
